# Babel 7 Typescript properties undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have the follow code which works perfectly with typescript and typescrip-loader. I use redux-actions

```
export class Auth  {

    private loginAction: string;

    constructor() { initAction() }

    initAction() {
        this.loginAction = createAction("LOGIN TYPE");
    }

    pulblic auth() {
         console.log(this.loginAction)
         return dispatch => dispatch(this.loginAction)
    }
}
```

When I use function auth()

//Before: using awesome-typescript-loader
Console.log(this.loginAction) -> function

//After: using babel 7 
Console.log(this.loginAction) -> undefined

Comment: Try with console.log(this.loginAction)

Comment: Still the same.